# CSS shouldn't change while the screen goes down with scrollTop

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Something goes wrong with my CSS when I activate the ScrollTop effect on my two buttons : the  css effects apply, despite :

```
.hcb_link a {
    color: inherit;
}

.hcb_link a:hover, a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The link becomes black and underlined when the page moves... I would like it to stay white and not underlined.

Is there something that I need to do on my JS ?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var the_id = $(this).attr("href"),
        yPos = $(the_id).offset().top,
        speed = 1500;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: yPos -71     // -71px pour prendre en compte la taille du bandeau supérieur.
    }, speed);
    return false;
});
```

```css
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.carrousel {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;

}

.hcb_link {
    background: #D5420F;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

.hcb_link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(215, 66, 34, .9);
}

.hcb_link a {
    color: inherit;
}

.hcb_link a:hover, a:active, a:focus{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carrousel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2 hcb_link">
                    <a href="#ancreProfessionnel">Vous êtes un professionnel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 hcb_link">
                    <a href="#ancreEtudiant">Vous êtes un étudiant</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ancreProfessionnel" class="hss_container light_background" style="min-height:520px;">
    <div class="max_width">

        <div class="hssc_title"><span class="third_color">Entrepreneurs</span>, démultipliez votre force commerciale grâce à des étudiants rémunérés au succès
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="ancreEtudiant" class="hss_container dark_background" style="min-height:490px; border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
    <div class="max_width">

        <div class="hssc_title"><span class="fourth_color">Étudiants des Grandes Écoles</span>, mettez vos compétences et votre énergie à profit
        </div>

    </div>
</div>       
    
<div id="ancreEtudiant" class="hss_container dark_background" style="min-height:490px; border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
  <div class="max_width">

    <div class="hssc_title"><span class="fourth_color">Étudiants des Grandes Écoles</span>, mettez vos compétences et votre énergie à profit
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

Thanks to @René and @Cthulhu, I've made some changes.

But it seams like despite everything, it is the Bootstrap that is triggered :

```
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This does not happen in the example you provided. Please give us more information about the browser you're using and maybe show us a live example of this problem you're facing.

Comment: I don't know if it's related but just so you know: `.carrousel a:hover, a:active` this rule applies for all `:active` links, not only in `.carrousel`, with correspondingly lower specificity.

Comment: I'm afraid René that I can't reproduce what happens on my computer with this example... What happens is just that the text "Vous êtes un professionnel" and "Vous êtes un étudiant" turn black and underlined while active (= while the screen scrolls down and while I don't clic elsewhere). And it seams like JS does it. As for my browser, I'm using Chrome.